# Eliminating end points automatically

Tags: qgis, point, machine-learning

In QGIS 3.10 I have a point file and I decided a colors palettes for it.
Let's say this palette is composed by 11 colours steps, from blue to red and its intermediates.

So, I would like to automatically find in the point file where is the entire palette.
Once found I would like to eliminate automatically the wings of this palette, the first three values and the last three values.

Does anybody think it is possible? If not, can I at least try to find where the entire palette is, without the elimination step?

[image]

I want to automatically find, in a set of points like this, the points that goes from blue to red, or the points that are near each other having a certain difference in values between them.

I want to find, for example, the point circled in black.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some example data or otherwise illustrate, what you're trying to do?

Comment: i edited my question, thank you.

Comment: yes this is the point i want to reach, finding cluster where all color are represented, or at least somewhere is visible quite all colours

Comment: very close, if there is this situation in which i have entire (or almost entire) palette it must be close. let's say maximun 100 meters from blu to red.

Comment: Help please is very important for me, also to understand if it is possible or not

Answer (score 3):

To get you started... One way could be to use python and [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) package:

> NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study
> of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

I dont think it's included in QGIS so you will have to install it.

You will very likely need to adjust the code to make it work which will be tricky if you are are not used to python.

First use Delaunay Triangulation to find id of each points neighbours. (You might ofc want to use some other way):
[image]

My sample data have integer values from 0 to 5, you will need to reclassify your data or change the code. Adjust and run the code and it should output a line layer:

```
import networkx as nx

triangles = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('triangulation_sub')[0] #Adjust layer name
points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ok_bs_riks_sample')[0] #Same

#Create a graph using triangulation layer
L = [[int(a) for a in f.attributes()] for f in triangles.getFeatures()]
G=nx.Graph()
for l in L:
    nx.add_path(G, l)

#Store data from "val" field in a dictionary
data = {f.id():f['val'] for f in points.getFeatures()} #Change 'val' to the name of your field in the point layer

def findPaths(G,u,n): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095646/finding-all-paths-walks-of-given-length-in-a-networkx-graph
    if n==0:
        return [[u]]
    paths = [[u]+path for neighbor in G.neighbors(u) for path in findPaths(G,neighbor,n-1) if u not in path]
    return paths

allpaths = []
to_find = [0,1,2,3,4,5] #Find 6 points with this sequence (or reversed)
for node in G:
    allpaths.extend(findPaths(G,node,len(to_find)-1))

found = []
for path in allpaths:
    seq = [data[p] for p in path]
    if seq==to_find:
        found.append(path)


#Create a vector layer for the found paths
pointdata = {f.id():f.geometry() for f in points.getFeatures()}
vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(triangles.crs().authid()), "Full_paths_{}".format('-'.join([str(v) for v in to_find])), "memory")
prov = vl.dataProvider()

for nodes in found:
    feat = QgsFeature()
    gLine = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(pointdata[node].centroid().asPoint()) for node in nodes])
    feat.setGeometry(gLine)
    prov.addFeatures([feat])

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]